# How to properly make an xts object

Tags: r, xts

I have data of times and prices, and I want to make an xts object. Therefore, I have written:

```
head(all)
class(all$Time)
class(all$Price)
all$Time<- as.POSIXct(all$Time) # convert time to a factor
class(all$Time)
xt<- as.xts(all, order.by= as.POSIXct(as.character(all$Time) ))
class(xt$Time)
class(xt$Price)
head(xt)
```

output

```
> head(all)

                           Time  Price
1 2015/06/29 09:30:00.127000000 163.98
2 2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000 163.92
3 2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000 163.98
4 2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000 163.98
5 2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000 163.98
6 2015/06/29 09:30:00.173000000 163.99
> class(all$Time)
[1] "factor"
> class(all$Price)
[1] "numeric"
> all$Time<- as.POSIXct(all$Time)
> class(all$Time)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> xt<- as.xts(all, order.by= as.POSIXct(as.character(all$Time) ))
> class(xt$Time)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
> class(xt$Price)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
> head(xt)
                    Time                  Price     
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015-06-29 09:30:00" "163.9800"
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015-06-29 09:30:00" "163.9200"
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015-06-29 09:30:00" "163.9800"
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015-06-29 09:30:00" "163.9800"
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015-06-29 09:30:00" "163.9800"
2015-06-29 09:30:00 "2015-06-29 09:30:00" "163.9900"
```

As you can see the xts object looks like a character. How can I properly make it so that it is just times and prices?

Comment: Would you share `dput(head(all))` after the posix conversion?

Comment: Try with this one liner: `xt <- with(all, xts(Price, as.POSIXct(Time)))`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your data has millisecond information, you could try this:

```
options(digits.secs=6)
all$Time <- strptime(all$Time, format ="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS")
xts_price<-xts(all$Price,all$Time)
colnames(xts_price) <- "Price"
#> xts_price
#                         Price
#2015-06-29 09:30:00.127 163.98
#2015-06-29 09:30:00.173 163.92
#2015-06-29 09:30:00.173 163.98
#2015-06-29 09:30:00.173 163.98
#2015-06-29 09:30:00.173 163.98
#2015-06-29 09:30:00.173 163.99
#> class(xts_price)
#[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also note that the xts object is no longer character because the `Time` column was omitted (as it's unnecessary, since the time is stored in the `index` attribute).  It was character before because you can't mix types in an xts object.